# IF a cell is blank show "empty" if not, add hours to it

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, time

Been trying to make this work for about a half hour or so and looking up references to ISBLANK or is null... isn't working as expected, even if it I reverse the THEN values.

What am I missing?

```
H4 =IF(ISBLANK(H3),"empty",B2+4/24) 
// H3: empty
// B2: 7:30 AM
// RESULT: 11:30 AM

H4 =IF(ISBLANK(H3),B2+4/24,"empty" ) 
// H3: empty
// B2: 7:30 AM
// RESULT: empty
```

Have looked at Google sheets help, various Stack Overflow answers, but still unable to get this to work.

ACTUAL OUTPUT

[image: Actual output]

EXPECTED

[image: Expected output]

Comment: the formula (1st one) seems good to go. what error are you seeing exactly?!

Comment: something like this? ```=IF(ISBLANK(H3),"empty",TEXT(B2+4/24,"hh:mm"))```?

Comment: you may want to test your values one by one, like.... what does ```ISBLANK(H3)``` return when you think it is so called "empty"? what does ```ISDATE(B2)``` return? the formula itself seems to be normal, so it could be a problem of input and output format

Comment: You are not telling what "expected" would mean. Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Comment: I added two images. It doesn't seem to understand empty vs not empty all the time @rockinfreakshow.

Comment: @Ping that did the trick, thanks! Put that in an answer so I can select it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the formula itself looks perfectly fine, but the result is not showing what you expected, try to test the input values with `=ISBLANK()`, `=ISDATE()`, etc. to see if there is any formating issue.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H3),"empty",TEXT(B2+4/24,"hh:mm"))
```

you can also try formating the input data with `TEXT()` function.